# Direction of angular parameters and centripetal acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

If the axis of rotation is not passing through the centre of mass but some other point of a rigid body then how do we define the direction of angular parameters that is angular velocity, angular acceleration and angular displacement.

For example :[image]

This is a sphere with a void in between rolling on a flat surface.C is the centre of mass and O is the axis of rotation.

So basically my question is, will the angular velocity of the point A be perpendicular to OA or CA? Also will the angular acceleration of A be parallel or antiparallel to the angular velocity and correspondingly the centripetal acceleration would be perpendicular to the angular velocity right? I am confused about this.

Answer (score 2):

If the body is rigid the the angular velocity is the same about **any** point on the body!

Imagine a line between $C$ and $O$ and relative to $O, \, C$ rotates by an angle $\theta$ clockwise ie the body has moved to the right.

Now consider that line from the point of view of position $C$.
$O$ has rotated by an angle $\theta$ clockwise whilst the body has moved to the right.

The webpage [Rigid Bodies](https://dynref.engr.illinois.edu/rkg.html) has some nice animations to illustrate this.

If there is no slipping then every point on the body is has a horizontal component of translational velocity $v = R\,\omega$ to the right as well as a component of translational velocity due to rotation about position $O$ which for position $C$ would be $\frac R2\,\omega$ vertically upwards.

Answer (score 0):

The angular velocity, is perpendicular to OA, therefore the centripetal a ist in direction AO,  in the moment of your sketch, the Point C is left of A, so the weight is slowing down the rotation, if C is right of A it is increasing the rotation in your indicated direction  of angular velocity